# I want to extract a string from a text file and output it as a text file again

Tags: javascript, html, input, output, txt

I want to extract a string from a text file, convert it to a word scrambler (I figured out that part) and output it in another text file.
I found some code to input a text file and extract the text:

```html
<html>
  <h4>Select un file con .txt extension</h4>
  <input type="file" id="myFile" accept=".txt" />
  <br /><br />
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
    var input = document.getElementById("myFile");
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    input.addEventListener("change", function () {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var myFile = this.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
          output.textContent = e.target.result;
        });

        reader.readAsText(myFile);
      }
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Input text and extract a text file

```html
<html>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Write Here" />
    </div>
      <div>
        <input type="button"id="bt"value="Save in a File"onclick="saveFile()"/>
      </div>
  <script>
    let saveFile = () => {
      const testo = document.getElementById("txt");
      let data = testo.value;
      const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: "text/plain" });
      const sFileName = "Testo.txt";
      let newLink = document.createElement("a");
      newLink.download = sFileName;
      newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
      newLink.style.display = "none";
      document.body.appendChild(newLink);
      newLink.click(); 
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

But I don't know how to output a string in the first code or how to connect it to the second code. Could someone please show me how to do it or explain how these codes work so that I could try to do it myself in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I will comment each line of JavaScript, that should help you understand.

```
<script>
    /*This creates a global variable with the HTML element input in it. */
    var input = document.getElementById("myFile"); 
    /*This creates a global variable with the HTML element div with id output in it. */
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    /* this 2 lines are used to set the source and the destination.
    The first will get where you put your file, in this case it's the input element.
    The second will get the div which content will be replaced by the content of your txt file. */
    
    /* Here we tell to our input element to do something special when his value changes.
    A change will occur for example when a user will chose a file.*/
    input.addEventListener("change", function () {
      /* First thing we do is checking if this.files exists and this.files[0] aswell.
      they might not exist if the change is going from a file (hello.txt) to no file at all  */
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        /* Since we can chose more than one file by shift clicking multiple files, here we ensure that we only take the first one set. */
        var myFile = this.files[0];
        /* FileReader is the Object in the JavaScript standard that has the capabilities to read and get informations about files (content, size, creation date, etc) */
        var reader = new FileReader();

        /* Here we give the instruction for the FileReader we created, we tell it that when it loads, it should do some stuff. The load event is fired when the FileReader reads a file. In our case this hasn't happened yet, but as soon as it will this function will fire. */
        reader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
          /* What we do here is take the result of the fileReader and put it inside our output div to display it to the users. This is where you could do your scrambling and maybe save the result in a variable ? */
          output.textContent = e.target.result;
        });
        /* This is where we tell the FileReader to open and get the content of the file. This will fire the load event and get the function above to execute its code. */
        reader.readAsText(myFile);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

With this I hope you'll be able to understand the first part of this code. Try putting the second part of your code instead of output.textContent and replacing data with e.target.result, that should do what you wish, but I'll let you figure it out by yourself first, comment on this answer if you need further help !

Here's a codepen with working and commented code:
https://codepen.io/MattDirty/pen/eYZVWyK

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful :)

Comment: I tried combining them but I get a C:\fakepath\Text.txt written inside the txt output

Comment: Thank you, you helped me so much, I have been studying how to do this for months and thanks to your help I did it in 2 days. I needed to fix the code for my necessities but I couldn't have done it without you <3

Comment: Glad to have helped ! Buona fortuna per il resto !